# How to stop undo from changing tool settings

Tags: texture-painting, weight-painting

Say I change the Brush Strength in Weight Paint mode and do some painting, then after undoing with Ctrl Z it reverts to it's prior setting. This also applies to other modes. The only fix I've found is to momentarily switch to object mode, but it is very annoying. I am currently using Blender 2.83.

Is there any way to change this? It is extremely frustrating.

Comment: ^This. I'm bookmarking this question. I'm really hoping there is an answer.

Comment: What version of Blender? I am using 2.9 builds and don't see this as a problem anymore, though I do remember it awhile back.